# ¿Cómo generar texto aleatorio? Token String

Tags: c#, random, tokens

**Estoy intentando generar una cadena de texto aleatoria de una determinada longitud fija.**

Ese texto sera utilizado como token. Los textos generados pueden llegar a repetirse, aunque es deseado que suceda con poca frecuencia (un par de veces por cada millón generado).

---

Primer opción: es usando la clase Guid y tomando un substring. Por ejemplo:

```
        int longitud = 7;
        Guid miGuid = Guid.NewGuid();
        string token = miGuid.ToString().Replace("-", string.Empty).Substring(0, longitud);
```

Pero viendo código algunos dicen que no es lo suficientemente aleatorio el texto que se genera.

---

Segunda opción: usando un numero aleatorio y un alfabeto para generarlo. Por ejemplo:

```
        int longitud = 7;
        const string alfabeto = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
        StringBuilder token = new StringBuilder();
        Random rnd = new Random();

        for (int i = 0; i < longitud; i++)
        {
            int indice = rnd.Next(alfabeto.Length);
            token.Append(alfabeto[indice]);
        }
```

**¿Como puedo generar tokens con cadenas de texto aleatorias?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si no van a ser cadenas largas me parece bien la opción del Guid pero en lugar de coger directamente el Guid como cadena (lo que va a reducir los caracteres a dígitos hexadecimales) puedes generar una cadena a partir de los bytes del Guid:

```
    int longitud = 7;
    Guid miGuid = Guid.NewGuid();
    string token = Convert.ToBase64String(miGuid.ToByteArray());
    token = token.Replace("=", "").Replace("+", "");
    Console.WriteLine(token.Substring(0, longitud));
```

Comment: Muy buena opción.
Le agregaría un filtro más:  .Replace("/", "");

Answer (score 1):

Una opción adicional es usar [Hash](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s02tk69a(v=vs.110).aspx), tienes el [hash preincorporado en `Object`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gethashcode(v=vs.110).aspx) o puedes usar [MD5](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5):

```
using System.Security.Cryptography;

using (MD5 md5Hash = MD5.Create())
{
    string hash = GetMd5Hash(md5Hash, Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
}
```

Resultando en una cadena de 32 símbolos hexadecimales. No es considerado seguro para criptografía (pero no has mencionado que lo vayas a usar para ello).

Otra opción es calcular un Hash con [SHA256](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.sha256(v=vs.110).aspx), que es ligeramente más complicado de usar:

```
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;

SHA256 mySHA256 = SHA256Managed.Create();

var hashValue = mySHA256.ComputeHash(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Guid.NewGuid().ToString()));
string hash = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(hashValue);
```

Pero que tiene menos colisiones.

Comment: Buena opción pero el alfabeto que genera el hash está limitado a a-f y 0-9. Por lo que deberían ser tokens largos para evitar colisiones.

Comment: SHA tiene menos colisiones que MD5; ambos tienen (hasta donde llega mi conocimiento) colisiones bajas.

Answer (score 0):

Este programa genera tokens en base a las sugerencias.
Las versiones incluyen MD5, SHA256, Guid y Random.
Se generan un millón de tokens y se cuentan los repetidos.

---

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Security.Cryptography;
    using System.Text;

    namespace ConsoleTokenTest
    {
        class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                int longitud = 7;
                int cantidadPruebas = 1000000;
                HashSet<string> shas = new HashSet<string>(),
                    md5s = new HashSet<string>(),
                    guids = new HashSet<string>(),
                    rands = new HashSet<string>();

                int repetidosSha = 0, repetidosMd5 = 0, repetidosGuid = 0, repetidosRand = 0;
                RandomToken aleatorio = RandomToken.Instancia();

                Console.WriteLine("** Inicio la generacion de tokens de longitud " + longitud.ToString());
                Console.WriteLine("** Cantidad pruebas: " + cantidadPruebas.ToString());


                for (int i = 0; i < cantidadPruebas; i++)
                {
                    string shatok = ShaToken.Generar(longitud);
                    if (shas.Contains(shatok))
                    {
                        repetidosSha++;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        shas.Add(shatok);
                    }

                    string md5tok = Md5Token.Generar(longitud);
                    if (md5s.Contains(md5tok))
                    {
                        repetidosMd5++;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        md5s.Add(md5tok);
                    }

                    string guidTok = GuidToken.Generar(longitud);
                    if (guids.Contains(guidTok))
                    {
                        repetidosGuid++;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        guids.Add(guidTok);
                    }

                    string randTok = aleatorio.Generar(longitud);
                    if (rands.Contains(randTok))
                    {
                        repetidosRand++;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        rands.Add(randTok);
                    }

                    if (i % 1000 == 0)
                        Console.Write(".");
                }

                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.WriteLine(String.Format(
                    "ShaToken \t Repeticiones {0} \t Genereados {1}", repetidosSha.ToString(), shas.Count.ToString()));

                Console.WriteLine(String.Format(
                    "Md5Token \t Repeticiones {0} \t Genereados {1}", repetidosMd5.ToString(), md5s.Count.ToString()));

                Console.WriteLine(String.Format(
                    "GuidToken \t Repeticiones {0} \t Genereados {1}", repetidosGuid.ToString(), guids.Count.ToString()));

                Console.WriteLine(String.Format(
                    "RandomToken \t Repeticiones {0} \t Genereados {1}", repetidosRand.ToString(), rands.Count.ToString()));

                Console.ReadKey();
            }
        }

        public class Md5Token
        {
            public static string Generar(int longitud)
            {
                string hash = string.Empty;
                using (MD5 md5Hash = MD5.Create())
                {
                    hash = GetMd5Hash(md5Hash, Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
                }
                return hash.Substring(0, longitud);
            }

            private static string GetMd5Hash(MD5 md5Hash, string input)
            {
                byte[] data = md5Hash.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input));
                StringBuilder sBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
                {
                    sBuilder.Append(data[i].ToString("x2"));
                }

                // Return the hexadecimal string.
                return sBuilder.ToString();
            }
        }

        public class ShaToken
        {

            public static string Generar(int longitud)
            {
                SHA256 mySHA256 = SHA256Managed.Create();

                var hashValue = mySHA256.ComputeHash(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Guid.NewGuid().ToString()));
                string hash = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(hashValue);

                return hash.Substring(0, longitud);
            }
        }

        public class GuidToken
        {
            public static string Generar(int longitud)
            {
                Guid miGuid = Guid.NewGuid();
                string token = Convert.ToBase64String(miGuid.ToByteArray());
                token = token.Replace("=", "").Replace("+", "").Replace("/", "");
                return token.Substring(0, longitud);
            }
        }

        public class RandomToken
        {
            const string alfabeto = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
            private Random _rnd;
            private static RandomToken _instancia;

            private RandomToken()
            {
                _rnd = new Random(DateTime.Now.Millisecond);
            }

            public static RandomToken Instancia()
            {
                if (_instancia == null)
                {
                    _instancia = new RandomToken();
                }
                return _instancia;
            }

            public string Generar(int longitud)
            {
                StringBuilder token = new StringBuilder();

                for (int i = 0; i < longitud; i++)
                {
                    int indice = _rnd.Next(alfabeto.Length);
                    token.Append(alfabeto[indice]);
                }

                return token.ToString();
            }
        }
    }
```

---

Los resultados fueron muy interesantes:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias por los aportes.